# Vue Warn: Property or method is not defined on the instance with axios

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios, vuex

I'm struggling with vuex store getters based upon axios calls;

I saw a lot of questions about the same issue, but none of them seems to resolve my problem. I guess it has something to do with the async calls and the dom but I'm not qualified enough to see exactly what.

I'm using Laravel-mix.

I've tried to put a v-if (with fdc length) around my input but to no avail.

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueRes from 'vue-resource';

Vue.use(Vuex)
//Vue.use(axios)
Vue.prototype.$http = axios
Vue.use(VueRes);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        fdc: {
                billet_200: 0,
                billet_100: 0,
                billet_50: 0,
                billet_20: 0,
                billet_10: 0,
                billet_05: 0,
                piece_02: 0,
                piece_01: 0,
                piece_005: 0,
                piece_002: 0,
                piece_001: 0,
                cartouche: 0,
             },
        loading: true
  },
  mutations: {
    loadFDC(state, fdc) {
      state.fdc.billet_200 = fdc.fdc_200
      state.fdc.billet_100 = fdc.fdc_100
      state.fdc.billet_50 = fdc.fdc_50
      state.fdc.billet_20 = fdc.fdc_20
      state.fdc.billet_10 = fdc.fdc_10
      state.fdc.billet_05 = fdc.fdc_05
      state.fdc.piece_02 = fdc.fdc_02
      state.fdc.piece_01 = fdc.fdc_01
      state.fdc.piece_005 = fdc.fdc_005
      state.fdc.piece_002 = fdc.fdc_002
      state.fdc.piece_001 = fdc.fdc_001
      state.fdc.cartouche = fdc.fdc_cartouche
    }
  },
 actions: {
    getFDC ({ commit }) {
      axios
        .get('http://localhost/stardustCaisse/public/api/getfdc/2019-04-23')
        .then(r => r.data)
        .then(fdc => {
        commit('loadFDC', fdc[0])
        console.log(fdc[0])
        })
    }
  },
  getters: {
    calculeTotal: state => {
      var billet200 = parseInt(state.fdc.billet_200, 10) || 0;
      var billet100 = parseInt(state.fdc.billet_100, 10) || 0;
      var billet50 = parseInt(state.fdc.billet_50, 10) || 0;
      var billet20 = parseInt(state.fdc.billet_20, 10) || 0;
      var billet10 = parseInt(state.fdc.billet_10, 10) || 0;
      var billet05 = parseInt(state.fdc.billet_05, 10) || 0;
      var piece02 = parseInt(state.fdc.piece_02, 10) || 0;
      var piece01 = parseInt(state.fdc.piece_01, 10) || 0;
      var piece005 = parseInt(state.fdc.piece_005, 10) || 0;
      var piece002 = parseInt(state.fdc.piece_002, 10) || 0;
      var piece001 = parseInt(state.fdc.piece_001, 10) || 0;
      var cartouche = parseInt(state.fdc.cartouche, 10) || 0;

      return (billet200 * 200) + (billet100 * 100) + (billet50 * 50) + (billet20 * 20) + (billet10 * 10) + (billet05 * 5) + (piece02 * 2) + (piece01 * 1) + (piece005 * 0.5) + (piece002 * 0.2) + (piece001 * 0.1);
    }
  }
})
```

And in my component:

```
<script>
  import { mapState } from 'vuex'
  import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
    export default {
    mounted () {
        this.$store.dispatch('getFDC')
      },
        computed: 
      mapState(['fdc']),
      ...mapGetters(['calculeTotal'])
    }
</script>
```

...

```
<input id="fdc_total" name="fdc_total" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Total" v-model="calculeTotal">
```

The error is the following:
[Vue warn]: Property or method "calculeTotal" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Any help to put my on the right path would be highly appreciated !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a missing curly bracket at the start of the computed block? Try...

```
computed:{
  ...mapState(['fdc']),
  ...mapGetters(['calculeTotal'])
}
```